# In my Git why this regtrans-ms NetHood@ OneDrive/ Pictures/ is coming and what this @ , and / depicts. I am new support my bubbling enthusiasm?

Tags: command-line-interface, git-bash, mingw-w64

```
 NTUSER.DAT{8e3c52a3-d577-11ec-ac6e-48e7da552404}.TM.blf
 NTUSER.DAT{8e3c52a3-d577-11ec-ac6e-48e7da552404}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
 **NTUSER.DAT{8e3c52a3-d577-11ec-ac6e-48e7da552404}.TMContainer000[enter image description here][1]00000000000000002.regtrans-ms**
```

*What this above bold line means and also tell about these symbol used on directories name 'xyz/' and normal xyz/ and Nethod@ ??*

```
**NetHood@**
 OneDrive/
 Pictures/
 PrintHood@
 Recent@
**'Saved Games'/**
 Searches/
 SendTo@
**'Start Menu'@**
 Templates **@**
 Videos/
 * WhatsAppSetup.exe* *

 gitdirectory/

 

ntuser.dat.LOG1
 ntuser.dat.LOG2
 ntuser.ini
```

Comment: None of the above seems to have anything to do with Git. What command did you run? You may be using "git-bash" but that's really just a port *of* Bash to Windows that comes with Git-for-Windows, so that Git can run: Git needs a POSIX-compatible shell, and bash-as-ported-to-Windows-for-Git is such a shell. But it's not Git itself, it's just this particular command line interpreter.

Comment: (Meanwhile, it seems you ran a command similar to `ls -F`. On a Unix/Linux system, the `-F` option to `ls`, as in `ls -F`, tells `ls` to add "flags" to each listed file-or-directory name. The suffix `@` flag represents a symbolic link, typically, and the suffix `/` represents a directory.)

Comment: The title of your question should be short, and not a very long sentence with a description that has (not much) to do with the rest of this (1!) question.  And do not change code (like bold) to mark something. Just give a proper description of the line (like line containing "regtrans-ms")

Comment: a question/answer about "regtrans-ms" is here: [Why does Windows keep regenerating unneeded .regtrans-ms files in my user folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/1370380/why-does-windows-keep-regenerating-unneeded-regtrans-ms-files-in-my-user-folder)

Answer (score 0):

That would be typical of a Git repository created at the root folder of your drive:

```
REM BAD!
cd c:\
git init .
git add . # don't do this
```

That would include all kind of special folders, including:

- OneDrive, which is synchronized with a Microsoft cloud drive
- `C:\users\default\ntuser.dat` for [user profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/user-profiles-and-logon/desktop-location-unavailable)
- ...

Solution: remove the `C:\.git` (hidden) subfolder if you had created a Git repository at the root folder of your drive.